# Key Value Array From String

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I have a key value pair string that I would like to convert to a functional array.  So that I can reference the values using their key.  Right now I have this:

```
$Array = "'Type'=>'Honda', 'Color'=>'Red'";
$MyArray = array($Array);
```

This is not bringing back a functional key/value array. My key value pairs are in a variable string which means the => is part of the string and i think this is where my problem is.  Any help would be appreciated.  All i am trying to do is convert the string to a functional key/value pair where I can grab the values using the key.  My data is in a string so please don't reply with the answer "take them out of the string."  I am aware that this will work:

```
$MyArray = array('Type'=>'Honda', 'Color'=>'Red');
```

But my probem is that the the data is already in the form of a string.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this. As such, you'll need to write a custom function to build the keys and values for each element.

An example specification for the custom function:

- Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split each element based on the comma.
- Iterate over the result and:

  - `explode()` on `=>`
  - Remove unnecessary characters, i.e. single quotes
  - Store the first element as the key and the second element as the value
- Return the array.

**Note**: if your strings contain delimiters this will be more challenging.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to "take them out of the string", as you say. But you don't have to do it manually. The other answer uses explode; that's a fine method. I'll show you another - what I think is the easiest way is to use `preg_match_all()` ([documentation](http://php.net/preg_match_all)), like this:

```
$string = "'Type'=>'Honda', 'Color'=>'Red'";
$array = array();
preg_match_all("/'(.+?)'=>'(.+?)'/", $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $key) {
    $array[$key] = $matches[2][$i];
}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: + This will work provided the keys and values do not contain the delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I'm assuming the data is well-formed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string and extract the data:

```
$string = "'Type'=>'Honda', 'Color'=>'Red'";

$elements = explode(",",$string);

$keyValuePairs = array();
foreach($elements as $element){
$keyValuePairs[] = explode("=>",$element);
}

var_dump($keyValuePairs);
```

Now you can create your on array using the $keyValuePairs array.

Comment: And to remove single quotes you can use $cleanString = str_replace("'","",$searchString);

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/asj0-qtxe) of one way you can do it -

```
$Array = "'Type'=>'Honda', 'Color'=>'Red'";
$realArray = explode(',',$Array); // get the items that will be in the new array
$newArray = array();
foreach($realArray as $value) {
    $arrayBit = explode('=>', $value); // split each item
    $key = str_replace('\'', '', $arrayBit[0]); // clean up
    $newValue = str_replace('\'', '', $arrayBit[1]); // clean up
    $newArray[$key] = $newValue; // place the new item in the new array
}
print_r($newArray); // just to see the new array
echo $newArray['Type']; // calls out one element
```

This could be placed into a function that could be extended so each item gets cleaned up properly (instead of the brute force method shown here), but demonstrates the basics.